# Implementing the custom suggestion for search activity android

Tags: android, searchactivity

I am implementing the custom suggestion list for search activity from this blog http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1689 in doSearchQuery not able understand what he did it. Another thing is when I search by typing for e.g. month name and start with the "A" it compare it and return those match result August, April etc. but in the suggestion list only display "a" with all match result like "j" is contain in January, June, July. But in suggestion list getting j, j, j only not this months name. where I am wrong or missing something I didn't understand

here is my code for SearchActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
    this.setDefaultKeyMode(Activity.DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL);

    final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();

    final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
        this.doSearchQuery(queryIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(queryAction)) {
        this.doView(queryIntent);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Create intent NOT from search");
    }

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(final Intent queryIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(queryIntent);
    final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
        this.doSearchQuery(queryIntent);
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(queryAction)) {
        this.doView(queryIntent);
    }
}
// here in this didn't under what he did one is getting intent and bundle but where he define it.
private void doSearchQuery(final Intent queryIntent) {
    String queryString = queryIntent.getDataString(); // from suggestions
    if (query == null) {
        query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); // from search-bar
    }

    // display results here
    bundle.putString("user_query", queryString);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("", "", queryString));

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    queryIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.e("query string", "query string "+queryString);
}

private void doView(final Intent queryIntent) {
    Uri uri = queryIntent.getData();
    String action = queryIntent.getAction();
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

here is my Provider, I need single line suggestion I am comment the second column

```
public class MySuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = MySuggestionProvider.class.getName();
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;
    private final static String TAG = MySuggestionProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
            "_id", // must include this column
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
//          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID };

    public MySuggestionProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        String query = selectionArgs[0];
        if (query == null || query.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMNS);

        try {
            List<String> list = callmyservice(query);
            int n = 0;
            for (String obj : list) {
                cursor.addRow(createRow(Integer.valueOf(n), query, obj));
                n++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to lookup " + query, e);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private Object[] createRow(Integer id, String text1,
            String name) {
        return new Object[] { id, // _id
                text1, // text1
                //text2, // text2
                text1, "android.intent.action.SEARCH", // action
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT };
    }
    private static final String[] months = {"January", "February","march","April","may","june","july","August","September","octobor",
        "november","december"};
    List<String> ls2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> callmyservice(String query){
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
            if(months[i].toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())){
                //if(months[i].equalsIgnoreCase(query.toLowerCase())){
                ls.add(months[i]);
            }
        }

        ls2.clear();
        ls2.addAll(ls);

        return ls;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the way how to implement custom suggestion. A little bit changes in this and you can implement search Suggestion Single or as Double line in suggestion list.

For the Single line suggestin I am explain first.

As from the questions code I changes some and implement the for single line suggestion list.

From the COLUMN object change this

```
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        "_id", // must include this column
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID };
```

now in createRow() time just pass the object one is ID and another is suggestion list value in query() method.

```
List<String> list = callmyservice(query);
int n = 0;
for (String obj : list) {
     cursor.addRow(createRow(Integer.valueOf(n),obj));
      n++;
}
```

now implement the createRow() like this.

```
private Object[] createRow(Integer id, String text1){
    return new Object[] { id, // _id
            text1, // text1
            text1, // data to sent back to activity and select
            text1, // data sent as extra data when select from suggestin list
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT};
}
```

Ok here is the snap hows it look when you implement this.

[image]

Ok Now for two line search suggestion list create COLUMN object like this

```
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        "_id", // must include this column
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID };
```

now implement createRow() method and call from query() like this
    // query() method
    List list = callmyservice(query);
    int n = 0;
    for (String obj : list) {
        // here query is your current typing text for search for text_1
        // obj was the match list found with this query as result and display for text_2
        cursor.addRow(createRow(Integer.valueOf(n), query, obj));
        n++;
    }

```
private Object[] createRow(Integer id, String text1, String name) {
    return new Object[] { id, // _id
            text1, // text1
            text2, // text2
            text1, // data to be sent when select from list as query
            text2, // data to be sent as extra string when select from list as result
            "android.intent.action.SEARCH", // action
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT };
}
```

and here is the view for two line search suggestion list

[image]

ok so hope that this will helpful to you.

Comment: sorry but what is that "callmyservice" at there, I could not understand

Comment: @kaplanfat it means the data comes from something you implement, it doesn't matter how for the above code to work, the only important part is that you acquire a `List<String>` from somewhere.